# How to handle input data on button press?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which runs but not the way it should. The user has to select a value from the drop-down list then, depending on the value selected, an area will be computed using the data in the `input` fields. The `switch` works fine because I can see the alert but the area returned (`aria1`/`aria2`) is shown as NaN.

FIDDLE HERE: https://jsfiddle.net/aLgvwq3r/

Select "Forma 1" and insert some values. Instead of NaN I should be getting a value for that area after I press the button.

It looks like it is not values from the inputs. What should I do?

```
function arie1() {
  var lungC = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lungC').value);
  var latC = parseFloat(document.getElementById('latC').value);
  var hC = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hC').value);
  var hBaza = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hTotal').value);
  var latBaza = parseFloat(document.getElementById('latBaza').value);
  var aria1 = 2 * lungC * latC + 2 * lungC * hTotal + 2 * latBaza * (hC + hTotal) + 2 * 0.5 * lungC + 0.5 * latBaza + 5; //se vor lua 5m2 de rezerva si se va mentiona pe site sa se mai adauge o marja de eroare
  document.getElementById('mpv').innerHTML = aria1;
  document.getElementById('mp').style.display = 'block';

}

function arie2() {
  var lungC = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lungC').value);
  var latC = parseFloat(document.getElementById('latC').value);
  var hC = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hC').value);
  var hBaza = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hTotal').value);
  var latBaza = parseFloat(document.getElementById('latBaza').value);
  aria2 = parseFloat(lungC * latC + 2 * lungC * hTotal + 2 * latBaza * (hC + hTotal) + 2 * 0.5 * lungC + 0.5 * latBaza + 5); //se vor lua 5m2 de rezerva si se va mentiona pe site sa se mai adauge o marja de eroare
  document.getElementById('mpv').innerHTML = aria2;
  document.getElementById('mp').style.display = 'block';
}

function switcherForma() {
  switch (parseInt(document.getElementById('select-forma').value, 10)) {
    case 1:
      alert("Ati ales Forma 1");
      document.getElementById('f1').style.color = "red";
      document.getElementById('calculeaza').addEventListener('click', arie1);
      break;

    case 2:

      break;

    case 3:

      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any jQuery at all in the code...

Comment: Can you explain properly what you are trying to achieve here ?

Comment: I have 3 shapes. From the `dropdown list` the user selects shape1/2/3. Depending on that choice I will change the way I compute the `area` (arie1/arie2 functions). I get the values from a form that has multiple inputs. But it looks like the script gets the values as soon as I select an option from the list. I need it to get the values when I press the button with the `id="calculeaza"`.

Comment: @ThanveerShah I added a fiddle and some additional explaining.

Comment: It's really hard to understand the code , But we will do our best to help you

Comment: You can ask here about parts of the code that don't make sense to you.

Comment: So when i click the submit button , All the values inside the input should be added and show the total value ?

Comment: There's an issue with your variables hBaza and hTotal I think...

Comment: @ThanveerShah Yes. And that value should be shown in the `span` inside H1 that appears after you press the button. (You have all the code on fiddle)

Comment: @MatthewPage What do you mean?

Comment: @VladutMaican -  You declare hBaza from the element hTotal, but in the main calculation you use the variable hTotal. Change hBaza to hTotal and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Heree you go ,

Let me know if this is what you wanted

Replace your `arie1` function with this:

```
function arie1() {
    var lungC = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lungC').value);
    var latC = parseFloat(document.getElementById('latC').value);
    var hC = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hC').value);
    var hBaza = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hTotal').value);
    var latBaza = parseFloat(document.getElementById('latBaza').value);
    var aria1 = lungC + latC + hC + hBaza + latBaza;
    document.getElementById('mpv').innerHTML = aria1;
    document.getElementById('mp').style.display = 'block';

    console.log(aria1);
  }
```

Comment: so you only replaced the `var aria1` value?

Comment: Yup basically. Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

When you calculate the result the variable `hTotal` is not a number, but an element.
Change the calculation to this and it works for me:

```
2*lungC*latC + 2*lungC*hTotal.value + 2*latBaza*(hC+hTotal.value) +2*0.5*lungC + 0.5*latBaza + 5
```